# Create symlink that works on different machine when pulled with git

Tags: git, bash, ubuntu

I have a repository on my local machine with a few symlinks. When I clone into it from a remote server, the links are broken.

I'm using this command to make the links (mac).

```
ln -s mySource/pathTo/file.txt file.txt
```

How can I make the link relative so when it gets pulled in, it uses the ubuntu file system path?

Comment: If these paths don't contain any code and are essentially local config files, would you consider adding those filepaths to a .gitignore file instead?

Comment: The code should figure out its environment with env vars or perhaps `find`.  Links arent that dynamic and won't provide the flexibility.

Comment: The code is shared among a bunch of different modules that make up a suite of programs

Comment: ln creates relative links by default. So your code should work. Didn't you mix up upper/lowercase letters?